# How extract single table data from fullbackup?

Tags: linux, unix, mysql, percona

We have a yesterdays "full backup file(daily_3101013.sql)" it's size is **1TB**. We are taking full bakup by using **Percona-XTRA BACKUP**. So now I want one table backup/data from my full backup file(daily_3101013.sql)for restoring/import purpose.

encountering problem with restoring the table. The error you are getting is supposedly **“Got error -1 from storage engine”**.

How can I do that?

please help me here.

Comment: I am assuming you don't have another TB free to extract and pull it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a bash script to spit a full DB dump to one SQL file per table.

Checkout and download the gist [Split MySQL dump SQL file into one file per table](https://gist.github.com/1608062)

To extract a single table run `mysql_splitdump.sh daily_3101013.sql mytable`.

```
#!/bin/bash

####
# Split MySQL dump SQL file into one file per table
# based on http://blog.tty.nl/2011/12/28/splitting-a-database-dump
####

if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
  echo "USAGE $0 DUMP_FILE [TABLE]"
  exit
fi

if [ $# -ge 2 ] ; then
  csplit -s -ftable $1 "/-- Table structure for table/" "%-- Table structure for table \`$2\`%" "/-- Table structure for table/" "%40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE%1"
else
  csplit -s -ftable $1 "/-- Table structure for table/" {*}
fi

[ $? -eq 0 ] || exit

mv table00 head

FILE=`ls -1 table* | tail -n 1`
if [ $# -ge 2 ] ; then
  mv $FILE foot
else
  csplit -b '%d' -s -f$FILE $FILE "/40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE/" {*}
  mv ${FILE}1 foot
fi

for FILE in `ls -1 table*`; do
  NAME=`head -n1 $FILE | cut -d$'\x60' -f2`
  cat head $FILE foot > "$NAME.sql"
done

rm head foot table*
```

Comment: I haven't tried this script for a dump as big as 1TB. You might just want to use csplit and forget about appending/prepending the head and foot. Also checkout the blog article [Splitting a database dump](http://blog.tty.nl/2011/12/28/splitting-a-database-dump).

Comment: i want only one table(key_tansactional table) from my full backup.how can i do this.please help me here.

Comment: You can do that with [cplit](http://www.squarebox.co.uk/cgi-squarebox/manServer/usr/share/man/man1p/csplit.1p#4) using %regex% instead of /regex/. I'll have a look for you (and add it to my gist).

Comment: @mithunakous K check it out if added the feature.

Comment: Thanks it was useful for normal backup.but my issue s with percona XTRA-BACKUP .it having the files like(.frm,.ibd) formate.so how can i get single table data from percona-xtrabakup file.

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or did you have `innodb_file_per_table` enabled during table creation? If so, you should be able to create a `mydb_back` dir in you mysql data dir and simply put all the files of the table there. If you're using InnoDB without this option, you can only restore the whole DB and than copy the table.